# Trying to understand behavior of python scope and global keyword

Tags: python-3.x, scope

```
def func():
    def nested():
        global x
        x = 1
    x = 3
    nested()
    print("func:", x)

x = 2    
func()
print("main:", x)
```

Output:

```
func: 3
main: 1
```

I'm new to programming. I want to know where I'm going wrong. As I'm new to stack exchange, please let me know if there are any issues with my question or how to improve it.

The way I am reading this code is:

1. x is assigned the integer 2.
2. the func() function is called.
3. x is assigned the integer 3.
4. the nested() function is called.
5. x is declared a global variable? #not really clear of the implications
6. x is assigned the integer 1.
7. print("func":x) #because x was made a global variable within nested() I expected the output to be 1.
8. print("main": x) #I believe this is because x was made a global variable?

I'm not clear on why the output is 3 in the first print command?

Comment: I think what you're missing is that x can be two separate variables, one local and one global, despite having the same name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question was asked perfectly fine. The reason why is because the `global x` was declared in the nested. Not in the whole program, so they're 2 different variables.

Answer (score 4):

In short, there are two different identifiers, `x`, being referenced here: one at the model level, and a different one local to `func`.

Your steps should read:

1. The identifier `x` at the top level (i.e. the module level) is associated with the value 2.
2. the `func` function is called.
3. The completely different identifier `x` which is local to `func` is associated with the value 3.
4. the `nested` function is called.
5. Python is told that, within this scope of `nested`, the `x` refers to the top level (module level) `x`. Note `global` doesn't mean "next level up", it means "the top/global level" - the same one affected by step 1, not the one affected by step 3.
6. The global (top level) `x` is associated with the value 1.

etc.

General hint: Every time you think you need to use `global` you almost certainly don't.

Comment: You might also want to mention `nonlocal` https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#nonlocal as that would yield a different result if used in `nested`

Comment: 6 could probably benefit from the clarification that in the REPL/module/whatnot the `x` is the same as the `global` x. And maybe start with the fact they are two different (if identically named) things. (translating the assumed steps into what actually happens like you do I think is a good way to go, nitpickery aside)

Comment: Thanks! Your answer made it very clear to me where I went wrong. 

I actually just downloaded an anki deck made by someone and this was one of the cards that I couldn't figure out.